# Definition of subobject

Tags: category-theory

In the definition of subobject there is an equivalence relation defined on monomorphisms into a fixed codomain.

My question is that how do we know that the collection of monomorphisms into a fixed codomain is a set?

Is it obvious? or Is it because we can define equivalence relation not only on a set but a class? I don't know.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: We don't, it's not obvious, and we're defining the equivalence relation on a class. This issue crops up already in $\text{Set}$. .

Answer (score 3):

It's not satisfied in general. This leads to the notion of a [well-powered category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/well-powered+category).

An example of a category which is not well-powered is the partial order $V \cup \{\infty\}$, where $V$ is some Grothendieck universe and $\infty$ is some new element with $x \leq \infty$ for all $x \in V$.

See [MO/93853](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93853) for abelian categories which are not well-powered.